# Incompatibilidad en el gradle de Android

Tags: android

Buenos días, acabo de terminar una app en la que estaba trabajando. Ahora quiero mejorarla añadiéndole recyclerviews en lugar de los listviews.

Este es mi gradle original:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"




}
```

Por ello en su gradle quiero añadirle las librerías correspondientes,que por lo que tengo entendido son estas:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Al añadirlo, me protesta esta librería:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Tras intentar compilar,me aparecen estos errores:

```
Error:(16, 30) error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
Error:(17, 38) error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(18, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
Error:(19, 35) error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
Error:(118, 13) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(118, 46) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(122, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
Error:(122, 33) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
Error:(135, 17) error: cannot find symbol class ResponseHandler
Error:(135, 61) error: cannot find symbol class BasicResponseHandler
```

Como puedo usar esas librerias y a la vez seguir utilizando el proyecto que esta terminado ya?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no encuentra clases que requiere tu proyecto en este caso   `org.apache.http.*`

que son las indicadas en el mensaje de error:

```
error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
error: package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
```

**La clases Apache no estan incluidas en el Android SDK por esta razón actualizar no es solución.**

El .jar que contiene estas clases Apache lo puedes descargar de **[Apache Software Foundation](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)**

agrega el `.jar` directamente al folder `/libs` y dentro de tu `build.gradle` habilita poder soportar esta librería:

```
android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

#### Deberías dejar de usar las librerías apache para conexión y usar **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**.

Comment: Gracias! Funcionó a la perfeccion....Por que sustituir unas por otras Elena?

Comment: Que bien Sergio, ¿porque sustituir? simplemente porque las clases Apache están marcadas como obsoletas, en algún momento futuro no podrás habilitarlas en tu proyecto por eso es mejor tratar de cambiarlas

Comment: Tomo nota de ello Elena, trataré de sustituirlas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error es por esto:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Cuando en las dependencias que has añadido indicas esto por ejemplo:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
```

Necesitarias cambiar la versión de android:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Y creo que aqui tambien:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: el problema que al hacer esto me fallan estas clases import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

Answer (score 1):

Debes actualizar el sdk de android studio.
[image: Actualizar]

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```