# Warning al construir el Gradle del modulo

Tags: java, android

He añadido una librería de `apache` y me da un `warning` al construir el
gradle. El gradle es el siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.aandg.demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.01"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: 
'4.5.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

El warning que me da es el siguiente:

> Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Las clases [Apache](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), actualmente son marcadas como obsoletas en Android**, es por eso que muestra el aviso, ya que podría (según Google) no funcionar adecuadamente.

tienes definida la propiedad para que puedan usarse las clases en tu proyecto

```
  useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

sin embargo la sugerencia es dejar de usar estas clases.

Revisa esta pregunta:
[Incompatibilidad en el gradle de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14822/incompatibilidad-en-el-gradle-de-android/14848#14848)

---

La opción es utilizar [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), aquí un ejemplo:

https://ihofmann.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/android-sending-post-requests-with-parameters/

Comment: gracias, ¿alguna sugerencia para usar otras clases distintas que me permitan hacer un post a un php en un servidor externo?

Comment: Definitivamente la opción es utilizar HttpURLConnection : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html